# Losing the original URL when using add_rewrite_rule

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to implement a rewrite rule so I can introduce a variable into my CPT's single page template. Basically I'm trying to include 'all' between my CPT's slug name of `work` and the category in the URL:

```
http://localhost/work/all/corporate/cognitive-puzzles/
```

The original URL should of course work as well:

```
http://localhost/work/corporate/cognitive-puzzles/
```

Here's what I have for my rewrite:

```
function wire_alternate_pdp_url() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('mode');
    add_rewrite_rule('work/all/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]&mode=all', 'top');
}
```

This almost works but for two issues. First being, the URL in my browser switches back to the form with the missing `all/` path. Second and more importantly, I get nothing for a `mode` within my single-project.php:

```
<?php 
    $mode = get_query_var('mode');
    echo $mode;
?>
```

This prints out nothing.

Any ideas on what I might be missing here? I feel I'm close but something isn't quite right.

Thanks in advance!

edit: forgot to mention, I'm running 3.6.1

Comment: It looks like your rule is not matching and some other rule is (so WP redirects you to correct URL). Are you sure that your rule is correct and it's matching?  Also... When are you calling this `wire_alternate_pdp_url` function (on which filter/action hook)?

Comment: I am calling `wire_alternate_pdp_url` on the `init` hook. I'm pretty certain the rule is matching. As an experiment, I changed the rule to this:         add_rewrite_rule('work/all/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=foo&mode=all', 'top'); and this resulted in URLs redirecting to a foo page I had made.

Answer (score 0):

wow, after more banging of my head against the wall, it took this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('work/all/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=project&name=$matches[2]&mode=all', 'top');
```

Two things actually, I had to include a `post_type=project` part as well as change `pagename` to `name`. If I remove either one, I get my previous results.

I am not sure why this set of values works when other examples didn't have this, but glad it works :)